# SharePoint 365 reminders for documents

Tags: workflow, document-library, content-type

I'm a Tech Author finishing up a contract for a client, and I need to make a recommendation for how they can manage their policy and process documents in SharePoint 365.

Basically, I want to give them an idea of how to arrange it so that all documents created with a specific content type in a library are flagged up for review on a regular basis; for example, every six months after the last major version update, and then every three months after each minor update until a major update is published. The reminder should be sent to a specified individual (normally the document creator, but if they leave the company, this would have to be changed) and probably the owner of the library.

With only a week left, I don't have time to deliver a full solution, but I really want to give them a head start. I'm guessing it would involve an information management policy and a custom workflow. I'd be very grateful for some hints, tips and pointers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried Using Microsoft Flow ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it. I've not had many opportunities to get SharePoint experience, and what I do know I've taught myself. 

Could it solve this problem, and if so, could you give me some pointers? Thanks.

Comment: I guess its possible but need to investigate on the logic where it checks the versions.